# How to put the a mysql column into an array with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I know you can put a row into an array but I am having trouble putting a column into an array.  I have no code yet.  I just wanna get the auto incrementing column "id" and put it into an array like like..

`$array[0] = 1;

$array[1] = 2;

$array[2] = 3;`

Comment: So what is your question? :-p

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
     $array[] = $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no direct way to output a 1-dimensional array out of a mysql query.

The result set will always be a 2-dimensional array (# of results x # of columns) that you will need to transform into a 1-dimensional if you really have to.

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner